# Rename tree tip labels by removing parts of character string

Tags: r, tree

Edit: clarification

I'm looking to rename the `tip.labels` of my nwk tree in R. An example of the current labels is:

`AB177299.1 Uncultured bacterium gene for 16S rRNA, clone: ODP1251B1.3`

but I'd just like the numerical ID at the start, so `AB177299.1`. My first inclination is to use `gsub()` on `tree$tip.label` but my issue is that every numerical ID and the following text are different for each tip. I then created a character vector of all numerical IDs which could be used as the tip names, if I were able to accurately replace each ID by using `order()`.

```
tip.ids <- rownames(taxonomy)
tree$tip.label[order(tree$tip.label) %in%
                         tip.ids] <- tip.ids
```

This didn't change anything within my tree, and I'm at a loss.

For reproducibility. `taxonomy` isn't included because you should only need `tip.ids`

```
> dput(tip.ids)
c("AB109878.1", "AB109879.1", "AB109880.1", "AB109881.1", "AB109882.1", 
"AB109883.1", "AB109884.1", "AB109885.1")

> dput(tree)
structure(list(edge = structure(c(9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 
12L, 13L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 6L, 15L, 7L, 8L), dim = c(14L, 2L)), edge.length = c(0.0341921975, 
5e-09, 0.12821348, 0.000367458500000008, 0.027617765, 0.037677039, 
0.028633124, 0.014468092, 5e-09, 0.009763081, 0.078168769, 0.021640684, 
0.341568464, 0.092957415), Nnode = 7L, node.label = c("root", 
"0.917", "", "0.929", "0.921", "0.302", "0.692"), tip.label = c("'AB109881.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-4'", 
"'AB109880.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-3'", 
"'AB109883.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-6'", 
"'AB109879.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-2'", 
"'AB109884.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-7'", 
"'AB109878.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-1'", 
"'AB109882.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-5'", 
"'AB109885.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-8'"
)), class = "phylo", order = "cladewise")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of these options will work for you.

```
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE)                                                                                                                                                               

text <- "'AB109880.1 Uncultured archaeon gene for 16S rRNA, partial sequence, clone:pMLA-3'"

# Option 1
paste0("AB", parse_number(text))
# Option 2
str_split(text, " ")[[1]][1]
```